# Tomcat console logs get output from my application

Tags: tomcat, logging, apache-axis, tomcat7, java.util.logging

I am using tomcat 7.0.32 and I have modified my logging.properties file to turn off the console appender as suggested here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Considerations_for_productive_usage

The trouble I am having is that I am deploying a modified version of axis2 that contains my internal application already deployed within it, and that is still logging to console.

I would like to turn this off or at least limit it because there is a lot of low level DEBUG level logs that do not seem to be dependent on the logging.properties file that tomcat uses.

Comment: Are you using any logging library like Logback or Log4J?

Comment: The problem was within my log4j configuration of my application where it was configured to write output to the console. I can updated it, but is there a good way for the web server to capture these and redirect it to a log file instead of console?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the log4j JAR from your application.